# Nginx: poxy_pass different locations to different ports

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, nginx-config

So basically, I want to poxy_pass the root location i.e. **[www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/)** to one port and all other routes i.e. **[www.domain.com/](http://www.domain.com/)*** to a different port. What I've done now is:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name www.domain.com;
        location /pricing {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4025;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4033;
        }
}
```

It works, but I do have other routes like *pricing* and sub-routes as well and if I navigate to those routes, it doesn't work as expected. So is there any global solution like:

```
location @other {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:4025;
}
```

**Update:**

I've done this and it solves my problem, but is it feasible?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name www.domain.com;

    location ~ [/](assets)(.*) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4025;
        }

    location ~ [/]((stylesheets)|(javascripts)|(images)|(fonts))(.*) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4033;
        }
    
    location ~ [^\/](.*) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4025;
    }

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4033;        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easiest and quick solution:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    
    server_name www.domain.com;
    
    location ~ [^\/](.*) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4025;
    }

    location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:4033;        
    }
}
```