# Rewrite or Redirect NGINX HTTPS to APACHE HTTP

Tags: docker, apache, nginx

is it possible to rewrite or redirect NGINX HTTPS url to APACHE HTTP url from the front end request? My website is using Nginx web server, but all the others files is in storage server with Apache as it's webserver. Whenever there are any request for files with certain format, it will rewrite to mydomain.com and it's path. This configuration works with NGINX HTTP to APACHE HTTP, bu now, when it turn NGINX HTTPS, it's not working. I couldn't figure what's are the issue here?

```
log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
                '$ssl_protocol/$ssl_cipher '
                '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log      /var/www/html/access.log main;
error_log       /var/www/html/error.log;

server {
                listen        443 ssl;
                server_name   www.example.com;

                ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/example.crt;
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/exacmple.key;

                root          /var/www/html;
                index         index.php index.html;

                location ~ (.*)\.pdf$ {
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.xy$1 redirect;
                }

                location ~ "^/photos/(.*)" {
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ "http:/mydomain.xy$1" redirect;

                }

                location ~ (.*)\.xls$ {
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.xy$1 redirect;
                }

                location ~ (.*)\.zip$ {
                     rewrite ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.xy$1 redirect;
                }

                location / {
                     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                }

                location ~ \.php$ {
                     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                }

                location ~ /\.ht {
                     deny all;
                }

 }

 server {
                listen      80;
                server_name www.example.com;
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }
```

- The website is in k8s env meanwhile the storage is an external server, outside the kubernetes. All ports have been configured and open.

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Try to proxy_pass the request towards http://mydomain.xy, as is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631299/nginx-poxy-pass-different-locations-to-different-ports

Comment: could it be that's its throwing CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) messages? that might happen when mixing HTTPS requests with normal HTTP ones